# Using for_each to iterate over form inputs

Tags: javascript, simple-form

I have two forms, one with `uk_inputs` and one with `international_inputs`. When one or more of the uk_inputs are filled out I want it so the international inputs in the other form are disabled. 
This currently works when the first uk_input is filled out, but I can't manage to make it work but iterating over all of them with for_each.
The first code snippet is where it works with the first uk_input and the second code snippet is my attempt to iterate over all of them.
apologies if this isn't clear. thanks

```html
$(document).ready(function() {
    var uk_input = document.querySelector(".uk_input");
    uk_input.onchange = function () {
        international_input =  document.querySelectorAll(".international_input")
        international_input.forEach(function(international) {
            international.disabled = uk_input.value
        });
    }
});
```

```html
$(document).ready(function() {
    var uk_input = document.querySelectorAll(".uk_input");
    uk_input.for_each.onchange = function (uk) {
        international_input =  document.querySelectorAll(".international_input")
        uk.international_input.forEach(function(international) {
            international.disabled = uk_input.value
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<%= fields.input :line_1, input_html: {class: "uk_input"} %>
<%= fields.input :line_2, input_html: {class: "uk_input"}  %>
<%= fields.input :line_3, input_html: {class: "uk_input"}  %>
<%= fields.input :town, input_html: {class: "uk_input"}  %>
<%= fields.input :county, input_html: {class: "uk_input"}  %>
<%= fields.input :postcode, input_html: {class: "uk_input"}  %>
```

```html
<%= fields.input :line_1, input_html: {class: "international_input"} %>
<%= fields.input :line_2, input_html: {class: "international_input"} %>
<%= fields.input :line_3, input_html: {class: "international_input"} %>
<%= fields.input :town, label: "City / Region", input_html: {class: "international_input"} %>
<%= fields.input :postcode, label: "Postcode / ZIP Code", input_html: {class: "international_input"} %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Syntax of a for each function:

The correct syntax of the `for each` function in JavaScript is:

```
let uk_inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".uk_inputs");
uk_inputs.forEach(input=>{
    input.addEventListener("click",event=>{
      //Code you want to run for every uk_inputs class input
  })
})
```

Also, as you can see detailed in the code above, to assign an event listener you must reference the DOM element you want to assign that event. This is a vanilla JavaScript solution. It's exactly the same result as it would be with jQuery.

[Here is a functional fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/k3llydev/Ljob8354/) In case you want to check it out.

#### Adjustments to fit your question:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    let uk_inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".uk_inputs"),
        international = document.querySelectorAll(".international");

    const enabledInternational = (enabled) => {
        international.forEach(input => {
            if (enabled) {
                input.removeAttribute("disabled");
            } else {
                input.setAttribute("disabled", `${enabled}`);
            }
        })
    }

    uk_inputs.forEach(input => {
        input.addEventListener("change", event => {
            enabledInternational(event.target.value === "");
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. However im not sure how to adapt this to my current code. What is the purpose of the click event? or is that just an example?

Comment: Yes, it is an example of how it works. The only thing that you were missing is the `forEach` syntax.